# React state gets "corrupted"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am working on a simple React.JS frontend piece.

I essentially have a browsing SPA for historical data. The design has a bunch of filters that I need to populate one at a time, starting the top one in my logic hierarchy.

I do something like:

```
  componentWillMount() {
    if (!this.props.advertisers) {
      this.props.loadAdvertisers();
    }
  }
```

Once advertisers array has been loaded, I map it to options of a select component (using `react-select`), set the selection to the first item in the list and load the next list - `campaigns`.

As far as I understand, the best way to do this is still `componentWillReceiveProps()` and I am a little perplexed how this should be done differently, given that `componentWillReceiveProps` is being phased out.

My code looks like:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (nextProps.advertisers && !this.props.advertisers) {
    const advertiser = nextProps.advertisers[0];
    this.setState({
      advertiser: {
        value: advertiser['id'],
        label: advertiser['name']
      }
    });
    nextProps.loadCampaigns(advertiser['id']);
  }
  // if campaigns list changed, reload the next filtered array
  if (nextProps.campaigns && this.props.campaigns !== nextProps.campaigns) {
    ...
  }
```

This worked fine, until I decided to add a loading indicator. I mapped state's `loading` property e.g. for `campaigns` it gets exposed via `this.props.campaignsLoading` then do:

```
return (this.props.campaignsLoading || this.props...Loading || ...) ? 
       <ProgressIndicator> : <MainContentPanel>
```

The problem is now, my state does not get set correctly inside `componentWillReceiveProps()`.

The project is using `@rematch` and I initially tried this with `@rematch/loading` plugin and when the problem happened, thought the plugin does it wrong, somehow. Then, I mapped `loading` properties manually, and just added two more `dispatch`es to manually set the loading `flag`.

All the props are being set/unset correctly, but my state is not being set and nothing works. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you add more code or create stackblitz link to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 1):

When you do

```
if (nextProps.advertisers && !this.props.advertisers) {
```

You are not comparing the next and the previous props. "this.props.advertisers" is probably already set so you never go into the setState line. Although using componentWillReceiveProps is no longer the recommended way to go ([You Probably Don't Need Derived State](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html)), what you probably want to do roughly is:

```
if (nextProps.advertisers && nextProps.advertisers !== !this.props.advertisers) {
```

Comment: Just to note that advertisers load just fine. There is no problem, so it does not need to get fixed. I do try to do what you are suggesting with campaigns and it is not working when loading is used. When there is no mapping of `loading` my code works fine. I must have been unclear in the original answer, since you answer is not addressing my problem. Sorry.